# Setting command parameter descriptions in discord.py

Tags: python, parameters, discord, discord.py, field-description

I am making a command in a bot to create a profile for a user. It is working fine, but I would like the description of the "name" parameter to say "What would you like to be called?".
Here is the code I currently have:

```py
import discord
from discord import app_commands
@tree.command(name="makeprofile", description="Make your own profile!", guild=discord.Object(id=000000000000))
async def make_profile(interaction, preferred_name: str, pronouns: str):
    db.insert({'id': interaction.user.id, 'name': preferred_name, 'pronouns': pronouns})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=app_commands%20describe#discord.app_commands.describe):

> ```py
> @discord.app_commands.describe(**parameters)
> ```
>
> Describes the given parameters by their name using the key of the keyword argument as the name.

So in your case:

```py
@app_commands.describe(preferred_name = "What would you like to be called?")
```

Comment: Tysm could not find this for the life of me